# How to check what character encoding is set on a console in which my program run?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, character-encoding, console

I know that in can be checked by user with `chcp` command. Here I ask how to do it from another program using handle to the console process.

Comment: I don't believe that can be done from another program.   If there's some way to cause chcp to be run in the console you could pipe output to a file and parse that.  Crude, but it would do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the code page of the console attached to the current process with [`GetConsoleCP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683162%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I can't see a corresponding function that works with an arbitrary console handle.

Comment: ...and, unfortunately, attaching to a process' console with `AttachConsole`, then using `GetConsoleCP` will *not* tell you the CP set for that console in the target process. To get the target's CP, you'd probably just about have to inject a thread into the target and have that execute `GetConsoleCP` in the context of the target process.